# Weird exception being thrown when initializing static variable

Tags: c#, wpf, static, argumentexception

I recently had a very weird `System.ArgumentException`.

The following code was at my `MainWindow` constructor on my WPF Application

```
CodeDefinitions.DEFAULT_AVALIABLE = (() => { return true; });
```

But every time a run the app, this is what I get: `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`

So obviusly there where something wrong, so I put the line inside a try/catch block, like this:

```
try
{
    CodeDefinitions.DEFAULT_AVALIABLE = (() => { return true; });        
}
catch()
{

}
```

And put an breakpoint at catch's '{', and this is what I got as $exception:

```
[System.TypeInitializationException] {"The type initializer for 'ComunicadorSerial.Classes.Utils.CodeDefinitions' threw an exception."}
```

That tells me nothing, so I took a look at `_innerException`:

```
_innerException {"An item with the same key has already been added."}   System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

As far as I know, this excepton is throw when using a Dictionary, but the most curious thing is that `DEFAULT_AVALIABLE` is a `Func<bool>`:

```
internal static Func<bool> DEFAULT_AVALIABLE;
```

Does anyone knows anything about this? It seems so dumb, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have something referencing `CodeDefinitions.DEFAULT_AVALIABLE` - perhaps adding its result to a dictionary?

Comment: Actually I don't, `CodeDefinitions.DEFAULT_AVALIABLE` is only used as default value for a class property, when there's no custom value defined - `public Func<Boolean> IsAvaliable;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializing a static variable invokes the static constructor if it has not been invoked previously.

Without seeing actual code it's impossible to tell whats wrong, but check your static constructor and the other static members for anything that might throw this exception.

Comment: You're right. There is an `static Dictionary` beeing initialized with a duplicated key. Thank you!